# Generate the Abacaba sequence

Tags: code-golf, string, sequence

This challenge is about printing the abacaba sequence of a specific depth.

Here is a diagram of the first 5 sequences (`a(N)` is the abacaba sequence of depth N, upper/lowercase is just to show the pattern, this is not needed in the output of your program):

```
a(0) = A
a(1) = aBa
a(2) = abaCaba
a(3) = abacabaDabacaba
a(4) = abacabadabacabaEabacabadabacaba
...
a(25) = abacabadabacabaeabacabadabacabafabacabadabacabaeabacabadabacabagabacabadabacabaeabacabadabacabafabacabadabacabaeabacabadabacabahabacabadabacabaeabacabadabacabafabacabadabacabaeabacabadabacabagabacabadabacabaeabacabadabacabafabacabadabacabaeabacabadabacabaiabacabadabacabaeabacabadabacabafabacabadabacabaeabacabadabacabagabacabadabacabaeabacabadabacabafabacabadabacabaeabacabadabacabahabacabadabacabaeabacabadabacabafabacabadabacabaeabacabadabacabagabacabadabacabaeabacabadabacabafabacabadabacabaeabacabadabacabajabacabadabacabaeabacabadabacabafabacabadabacabaeabacabadabacabagabacabadabacabaeabacabadabacabafabacabadabacabaeabacabadabacabahabacabadabacabaeabacabadabacabafabacabadabacabaeabacabadabacabagabacabadabacabaeabacabadabacabafabacabadabacabaeabacabadabacabaia...
```

As you can probably tell, the n'th abacaba sequence is the last one with the n'th letter and itself again added to it. (`a(n) = a(n - 1) + letter(n) + a(n - 1)`)

Your task is to make a program or function that takes an integer and prints the abacaba sequence of that depth. The output has to be correct at least for values up to and including 15.

Comment: Wouldn't the sequence be undefined after ₂₅?

Comment: @Legion OP's mentioned that "The output has to be correct at least for values up to and including 15", so it doesn't matter.

Comment: @nicael I know, I was just wondering how (∞) would be defined.

Comment: Huh. I had been contemplating posting this challenge.

Comment: Also known as the **ruler sequence** (but with letters instead of numbers), for something more easily Google-able.

Comment: Does the input have to be in decimal?

Comment: Why is a(0)="a"? Why not ""?

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy Because this is how the famous sequence is defined.

Comment: For what it's worth, any valid solution to this problem is also the solution to the **Towers of Hanoi** puzzle for _N_ disks.

Comment: Can we use 1-based indexing instead of 0-based indexing?

Comment: These are also called [sesquipowers or Zimin words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesquipower).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Pyth, 11 bytes

```
u++GHG<GhQk
```

Simple reduction.

Comment: @Loovjo Oh. Makes no sense, `0` should be the empty sequence IMO, but I'll conform to the question...

Comment: Yeah, simple. _goes and bangs head on wall_

Comment: @JAtkin Open up Pyth's `rev-doc.txt` next to this answer, and it should readily show itself to be simple.

Comment: Hehehe, not what I meant (I don't know pyth, so....)

Answer (score 7):

### Python, 44 bytes

```py
f=lambda n:"a"[n:]or f(n-1)+chr(97+n)+f(n-1)
```

Looks suspiciously might-be-golfable.

Answer (score 7):

### Haskell, <s>39</s> 37 bytes

```
a 0="a"
a n=a(n-1)++['a'..]!!n:a(n-1)
```

Usage example: `a 3` -> `"abacabadabacaba"`.

Edit: @Angs found two bytes to save. Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't `a n=a(n-1)++[97+n]++a(n-1)` work? Can't test right now.

Comment: @Seeq: no, `[97+n]` is a list of `Integer` and `a(n-1)` is a list of `Char` (aka `String`). You cannot concatenate lists with different types. `toEnum` makes a `Char` out of the `Integer`.

Comment: Ah, I always thought Char was just a specialized integer in Haskell.

Comment: `['a'..]!!n` is 2 bytes shorter than `toEnum(97+n)`

Comment: @Angs: Good catch! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

## Pyth, <s>14</s> 13 bytes

Thanks to Jakube for saving a byte!

```
VhQ=+k+@GNk;k
```

A solution with 14 bytes: `VhQ=ks[k@GNk;k`.

Explanation:

```
VhQ=+k+@GNk;k

               # Implicit: k = empty string
VhQ            # For N in range input + 1      
   =           # Assign k
      +@GNk    # Position N at alphabet + k
    +k         # k + above
           ;   # End loop
            k  # Print k
```

Try it [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VhQ%3D%2Bk%2B%40GNk%3Bk&input=3&debug=0)!

Comment: Shouldn't "N in range" be on the `V` line? `hQ` is just `eval(input) + 1`

Comment: @Loovjo Yeah, that's better and less confusing :)

Comment: You can shorten `=k` to `=`. Pyth will automatically assign the result to `k`, since `k` is the first variable in the expression `+k+@GNk`.

Comment: @Jakube Thank you very much! :)

Comment: I have a different answer for this challenge. It won't beat this solution, but it does illustrate a technique for giving the first n characters of the sequence: ``Vt^2Q=+k@Gx_.BhN`1)k`` (In this instance, it's set to give the first 2^Q-1 characters as the challenge requires, but you can see how to change that.)

Comment: Actually, this is shorter (for the same purpose as prev comment): ``sm@Gx_.Bd`1St^2Q``

Comment: And here's an even better way to find the exponent of 2 (thanks to isaacg): `sm@G/Phd2t^2Q`. This one actually ties this answer.

Answer (score 6):

## Brainfuck, 157 bytes

```
,+>-[>++<-----]>----->>+<<<<[->>[[->>[>>>]<+<+<[<<<]>>[>>>]<]>>[>>>]<[-<<[<<<]>>[>>>]<+>>[>>>]<]+>+<<<[<<<]>>[>>>]+[>>>]<]<<<+>>[<-<<]<]>>>>[>>>]<<<<<<[<<.<]
```

Input is given in binary.

The basic idea is to repeatedly duplicate the current sequence (starting with "a") and to increment the last element after each iteration:

1. a → aa → ab
2. ab → abab → abac
3. abac → abacabac → abacabac
4. ...

When all of this has been done the specified amount of times, the result gets printed excluding the last element.

### In-depth explanation

The memory is arranged in the following way:

```
.---------.-.-----.----.---.-----.----.---.---
|Countdown|0|Value|Copy|End|Value|Copy|End|...
'---------'-'-----'----'---'-----'----'---'---

            |--Element 1---|--Element 2---|
```

**Countdown** holds the number of copy cycles that are yet to be executed. The ABACABA sequence is stored in adjecent blocks, each made up of 3 cells. **Value** holds the character of the element (i.e. "A","B","C"...). The **Copy** flag indicates whether or not the corresponding element needs to be copied within the current copying cycle (0=copy, 1=don't). The **End** flag is set to 0 for the last element while it is being copied (it's 1 in all other cases).

Now to the actual (slightly ungolfed) program:

```
,                       read Countdown from input
+                       add 1 to avoid off-by-one error
>-[>++<-----]>-----     initialize value cell of first element to 97 ("a")
>>+                     set End flag of first element to 1
<<<<                    move to Countdown
[                       loop until Countdown hits 0 (main loop)
    -                   decrement Countdown
    >>                  move to Value cell of first element
    [                   copying loop
        [               duplication sub-loop
            -           decrement Value cell of the element to copy
            >>          move to End flag
            [>>>]       move to End flag of the last element
            <+<+        increment Copy and Value cell of last element (Copy cell is temporarily abused)
            <           move to End flag of second to last element
            [<<<]>>     move back to Copy cell of first element
            [>>>]<      move to Value cell of the first element where the Copy flag is 0
        ]
        >>[>>>]<        move to (abused) Copy flag of the last element
        [               "copy back" sub-loop
            -           decrement Copy flag
            <<          move to End flag of second to last element
            [<<<]>>     move back to Copy cell of first element
            [>>>]<      move to Value cell of the first element where the Copy flag is 0
            +           increment Value cell
            >>[>>>]<    move back to Copy flag of the last element
        ]
        +>+             set Copy and End flag to 1
        <<<             move to End flag of second to last element
        [<<<]>>         move back to Copy cell of first element
        [>>>]<          move to Value cell of the first element where the Copy flag is 0
        >+<             set Copy flag to 1
        >[>>>]<         move to Value cell of the next element to copy
    ]                   loop ends three cells behind the last "valid" Value cell
    <<<+                increment Value cell of last element
    >>                  move to End flag
    [<-<<]              reset all Copy flag
    <                   move to Countdown
]
>>>>                    move to End flag of first element
[>>>]<<<                move to End flag of last element                
<<<                     skip the last element
[<<.<]                  output Value cells (in reverse order, but that doesn't matter)
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!  I'd be interested in a more detailed breakdown!

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic Thanks for your reply :) I have now added a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 5):

### [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), <s>37</s> 32 bytes

```
$
aa
(T`_l`l`.$
)`1(a.*)
$1$1
z
```

The trailing linefeed is significant. Input is taken [in unary](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5343/can-numeric-input-output-be-in-unary).

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JAphYQooVGBfbGBsYC4kCilgMShhLiopCiQxJDEKego&input=MTExMQ)

Comment: It does not work.

Comment: @KennyLau yes, because Retina changed since I posted this answer. If you check out the release that was most recent when this was posted directly from GitHub, it will work with that.

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 36 bytes

```hs
tail.(iterate((:"a").succ=<<)"_a"!!)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHBCoAgDADQX5nSQQ956Rb6J0GMoTUykVy/33rvxHHlWrWkTQW5BseSH5Ts3GrR@jBeohSjtztaY7zeyA0S9IebwAQFFv2oVDyGztT7Dw)

This uses a different recursive method from most of the other answers. To get the next string in the sequence, we don't join two copies in the previous string with a new letter in between, but instead increment every letter and intersperse `a`'s.

```hs
aba -> bcb -> abacaba
```

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>43</s> 42 bytes

```js
a=n=>n?a(--n)+(n+11).toString(36)+a(n):"a"
```

*A byte saved thanks to [@Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil)!*

Yet another simple recursive solution...

Comment: `(n+11).toString(36)` saves you 1 byte, and works for up to a(25)!

Comment: @Neil Implemented. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 12 bytes (non-competitive)

Code:

```
'aIGDN>.bsJl
```

I'll be damned. I fixed a lot of bugs thanks to this challenge haha.

Explanation:

```
'aIGDN>.bsJl

'a             # Push the character 'a'
  I            # User input
   G           # For N in range(1, input)
    D          # Duplicate the stack
     N         # Push N
      >        # Increment
       .b      # Convert to alphabetic character (1 = A, 2 = B, etc.)
         s     # Swap the last two elements
          J    # push ''.join(stack)
           l   # Convert to lowercase
               # Implicit: print the last item of the stack
```

Comment: Why is it non-competitive?

Comment: @Loovjo I fixed the bugs _after_ the challenge was posted, therefore it's non-competitive :(

Answer (score 4):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) `-r`, 43 bytes

```
def f:.-1|[[97]][.+1]//f+[.+98]+f;f|implode
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z8lNU0hzUpP17AmOtrSPDY2Wk/bMFZfP00byLC0iNVOs06rycwtyMlPSf3/34DLkMuIy5jLhMuUy@xffkFJZn5e8X/dIgA)

---

With the capitalization pattern from the example outputs, 58 bytes:

```
def f:[[65]][.]//([.-1|f[]%32+96,.+66]|.+.)[:-1];f|implode
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFLDkAwEADQ/ZzCRkKqQ30mwVEms6MJQf2WPbvx3nqpTrNP/MBMnQijlGXGaF30LGlTm54KNEQS0WDOg3Uy@rjs5xamWbUCBzU00EIH9IXzXcLxqL1/)

```
def f:    ...       ;  define a filter named f
      [[65]][.]        base case, if the argument . is 0, return [65]
      //               otherwise
         .-1|f         call the filter recursively
         []%32+96      convert each codepoint to lower case
          ,.+66        append .+66 (. is now the filter argument -1)
         [ ... ]       collect all codepoints in an array
         |.+.          and repeat that array twice
         [:-1]         remove the last integer
f|implode              call the filter on the input and convert the result to a string
```

Answer (score 3):

### CJam (14 bytes)

```
'aqi{'b+1$++}/
```

[Online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code='aqi%7B'b%2B1%24%2B%2B%7D%2F&input=4)

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby (1.9 and up), 38 bytes

`?a` is a golfier way to write `"a"` but looks weird when mixed with ternary `?:`

```
a=->n{n<1??a:a[n-1]+(97+n).chr+a[n-1]}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 48 bytes

```r
f=function(n)if(n)paste0(a<-f(n-1),letters[n],a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P802rTQvuSQzP08jTzMzDUgUJBaXpBpoJNroAnm6hpo6OaklJalFxdF5sTqJmv/TNIw0udI0zDT/AwA)

Simple recursion.

Comment: Uh, what is paste0???

Comment: @Xi'an `paste0` is equivalent to `paste` with `sep=""`, so you avoid the spaces between letters that `paste` would add by default.

Answer (score 3):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 51 bytes

```
[range(.)+97|[.]|implode]|reduce.[]as$i("a";.+$i+.)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z@6KDEvPVVDT1Pb0rwmWi@2JjO3ICc/JTW2pig1pTQ5VS86NrFYJVNDKVHJWk9bJVNbT/P/f1MA)

My life has improved significantly since I found `reduce` in this language.

-16 bytes from ovs.

Answer (score 3):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 31 bytes

```
_-)"(;;
(. ?  {_
@  +}989
   1_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P8/XldTScPamktDT8FeQaE6nstBQUG71tLCkktBQcEw/v9/YwA)

I feel like this can be rearranged to be golfier, but a better layout eludes me. I also have a [cleaner 1-indexed version](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P9fwV5bScPamktPW0FJQaE6nkspXkGp1tLckstBQUFT6f9/EwA) which has a higher ratio of walls. This uses [xnor's method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/193729/76162) of repeatedly incrementing the string and interspersing with `a`s.

Answer (score 2):

## Python, <s>62</s> <s>54</s> <s>46</s> 45 bytes

I would like to think that this code can still be golfed down somehow.

Edit: Bug fix thanks to Lynn. -1 byte thanks to squid.

```python
a=lambda n:n and a(n-1)+chr(97+n)+a(n-1)or'a'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jcg9CoAwDAbQ3VNka0JxEAdR8DDR@hPQrxK6ePo6@Mb3vOXM6GvV@dJ7SUqYQIpEymg7ievpPA4REv/IHjTUPTsZGcgVx8aDTA09biisbCL1Aw)

Comment: Output should be in all-lowercase. The uppercase in the question is just for clarity about the repetition.

Comment: Whoops. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Blargle. Thanks @user81655

Comment: This is invalid (it never terminates — try it). Even in the base case, the recursive part of the expression is evaluated.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks @Lynn!

Comment: I'm late, but [45 bytes](https://tio.run/##Jcg9CoAwDAbQ3VNka0JxEAdR8DDR@hPQrxK6ePo6@Mb3vOXM6GvV@dJ7SUqYQIpEymg7ievpPA4REv/IHjTUPTsZGcgVx8aDTA09biisbCL1Aw "Python 3 – Try It Online") with chained comparison

Answer (score 2):

## C#, 59 bytes

```
string a(int n){return n<1?"a":a(n-1)+(char)(97+n)+a(n-1);}
```

Just another C# solution...

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 33 bytes

```perl
map$\.=chr(97+$_).$\,0..pop;print
```

No real need for un-golfing. Builds the string up by iteratively appending the next character in sequence plus the reverse of the string so far, using the ASCII value of 'a' as its starting point. Uses `$\` to save a few strokes, but that's about as tricky as it gets.

Works for `a(0)` through `a(25)` and even beyond. Although you get into extended ASCII after `a(29)`, you'll run out of memory long before you run out of character codes:

`a(25)` is ~64MiB. `a(29)` is ~1GiB.

To store the result of `a(255)` (untested!), one would need 2^256 - 1 = 1.15x10^77 bytes, or roughly **1.15x10^65 1-terabyte drives.**

Comment: We need those atom-shudder yottabyte drives, _now!_

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 14 bytes

```
0i:"t@whh]97+c
```

This uses [version 8.0.0](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/releases) of the language/compiler, which is earlier than the challenge.

#### Example

```
>> matl
 > 0i:"t@whh]97+c
 >
> 3
abacabadabacaba
```

#### Explanation

The secuence is created first with numbers `0`, `1`, `2`, ... These are converted to letters `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'` at the end.

```
0         % initiallize: a(0)
i:        % input "N" and create vector [1, 2, ... N]
"         % for each element of that vector
  t       % duplicate current sequence
  @       % push new value of the sequence
  whh     % build new sequence from two copies of old sequence and new value
]         % end for
97+c      % convert 0, 1, 2, ... to 'a', 'b', 'c'. Implicitly print
```

#### Edit

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MGk6InRAd2hoXTk3K2M&input=Mw)

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, <s>36</s> 32 bytes

```
##<>#&~Fold~Alphabet[][[;;#+1]]&
```

Have you ever watched TWOW 11B?

Comment: There is no need for the `"",` and then you can use infix notation for `Fold`.

Comment: #1 causes null `<>`s, and #2 only works for binary functions.

Comment: Did you post this comment on the answer you intended? Because I have no idea what you mean. :)

Comment: *#1 causes StringJoin to join nulls, and #2 only works for binary or associative functions. (x~Fold~y~Fold~z=Fold[x,Fold[y,z]] instead of Fold[x,y,z])

Comment: Oh you mean "suggestion #1". No it doesn't cause Nulls. Why would it?

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant `""`, not `"",`. With that they both work. Implementing.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 7, 158 bytes

```
class B{public static void main(String[]a){a('a',Byte.valueOf(a[0]));}static void a(char a,int c){if(c>=0){a(a,c-1);System.out.print((char)(a+c));a(a,c-1);}}}
```

I like to lurk around PPCG and I would enjoy being able to vote/comment on other answers.

Input is given as program parameters. This follows the same format as many other answers here in that it's a straight forward recursive implementation. I would have commented on the other answer but I don't have the rep to comment yet. It's also slightly different in that the recursive call is done twice rather than building a string and passing it along.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG then! I hope you'll do some more than voting and commenting in the future (but don't feel like you have to). :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 12 bytes

```
!¡S+oṠ:o→▲"a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR0A4v9odXNr//8hwqFTK2/huaA6b@KGkuKWsiJh////NA)

Uses 1-based indexing, which I hope is OK.

### Explanation

```
!             (                                          !!)
 ¡             iterate(                              )
  S                        <*>
   +                   (++)
    o                         (                     )
     Ṡ                         join$   .
      :                             (:)
       o                                    .
        →                               succ
         ▲                                   maximum
          "a                                          "a"

              (iterate((++)<*>(join$(:).succ.maximum))"a"!!)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vim](https://www.vim.org), 35 bytes

```
:h<_
jjYZZpqqv|yPyl/<c-r>"
xq{Dddl@-@qD
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/3yrDJp4rKysyKqqgsLCspjKgMkffJlm3yE6Jq6Kw2iUlJcdB16HQ5f9/4/@6ZQA)

#### Explanation

The buffer starts with a single line containing the input integer.

```
:h<_
jjYZZp
```

[Yank the lowercase alphabet from the help file.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97868/16766) Paste it on a new line below the integer, leaving the cursor on the first character of the second line.

```
qq
```

Start recording macro `q`. This will be our "loop."

```
v|y
```

Using visual mode, select everything from the current character to the beginning of the line, inclusive, and yank it. This leaves the cursor on the first character of the line.

```
P
```

Paste the yanked text to the left of the cursor. The cursor is now on the last of the pasted characters.

```
yl
```

Yank that character.

```
/<c-r>"
x
```

Find the next occurrence of the just-yanked character. Delete it.

```
q
```

Stop recording the macro. Conveniently, this first time through the macro has left the alphabet unchanged. The only effect is that the cursor has moved from the `a` to the `b`.

```
{Dddl
```

Go to the beginning of the buffer. Delete the contents of the first line (the input number). Then delete the (now-empty) first line. Move the cursor one character to the right so as to start on `b`.

```
@-@q
```

Execute the macro *N* times, where *N* is the number we just deleted.

```
D
```

Delete the unused remainder of the alphabet.

---

Normally, the `@-@q` idiom is fraught with peril if the number has a chance of being zero, because `0` is not a valid count in Vim; instead, it is treated as a separate command that move the cursor to the beginning of the line. However, in this particular case, an input of `0` is no problem at all:

```
@-
```

Move the cursor to the beginning of the line.

```
@q
```

Execute the macro once. Recall that executing the macro with the cursor on the `a` leaves the alphabet unchanged and the cursor on the `b`.

```
D
```

Delete everything to the end of the line--which leaves only the `a`, exactly the output we want.

Answer (score 2):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang) (v2.0-alpha), 37 bytes

```
;=q+96=n+1P;=x"";W=n-nT=x++xA-q n xOx
```

[Try it online!](https://knight-lang.netlify.app/v2#WyI7PXErOTY9bisxUDs9eFwiXCI7Vz1uLW5UPXgrK3hBLXEgbiB4T3giLCIzIl0=)

Expanded

```
; = q (+ 96 (= n (+ 1 PROMPT)))
; = x ""
; WHILE (= n (- n TRUE))
    = x (+ (+ x (ASCII (- q n))) x)
: OUTPUT x
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `J`, 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Oėıf2c;⁺Ä
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0kpdS7IKlpSVpuhbr_I9MP7IxzSjZ-lHjrsMtS4qTkouhUgsWmkAYAA)

Port of emanresu A's Vyxal answer.

##### Explanation

```python
Oėıf2c;⁺Ä  # Implicit input
O          # Push 2 ** input
 ė         # Push [1..that)
  ı   ;    # Map:
   f       #  Prime factors
    2c     #  Count 2s
       ⁺Ä  # Letter of alphabet
           # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 61 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 7.625 bytes

```
¤$(nøAȮW∑
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyI9IiwiIiwiwqQkKG7DuEHIrlfiiJEiLCIiLCI1Il0=)

Uses 1-indexing.

### Explained

Generated using Luminespire

```
¤$(nøAȮW∑
¤$         # Push an empty string under the input
  (        # For each n in the range [1, input]:
   nøA     #   Get the nth letter of the alphabet
      Ȯ    #   Push a copy of the item under the top of the stack. This leaves the stack as [already generated, new letter, already generated]
       W∑  #   Wrap and sum the stack
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript, <s>65</s> 57<sup>1</sup> bytes

```
n=>eval('s="a";for(i=0;i<n;i++)s+=(i+11).toString(36)+s')
```

Demo:

```js
function a(n){
  return eval('s="a";for(i=0;i<n;i++)s+=(i+11).toString(36)+s')
}
alert(a(3))
```

<sup>1 - thanks Neil for saving 8 bytes</sup>

Comment: `(i+11).toString(36)` saves you 6 bytes.

Comment: @Neil Haha, that's a clever hack

Comment: Oh, and if you move the assignment `s="a";` to before the `for` then it becomes the default return value and you can drop the trailing `;s` for another 2 byte saving.

Comment: @Neil Nice, didn't know about that.

Comment: I think you can save a byte by incrementing `i` inline and dropping the increment in the for loop. So... `for(i=0;i<n;)s+=(i+++11)...`

Comment: ...and also, why use `eval`?

Comment: That looks slightly syntactically incorrect. How about `...(++i+10)...`?

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 46 bytes

```
If[#<1,"a",(a=#0[#-1])<>Alphabet[][[#+1]]<>a]&
```

Simple recursive function. Another solution:

```
a@0="a";a@n_:=(b=a[n-1])<>Alphabet[][[n+1]]<>b
```

Answer (score 1):

## K5, 18 bytes

```
"A"{x,y,x}/`c$66+!
```

Repeatedly apply a function to a carried value (`"A"`) and each element of a sequence. The sequence is the alphabetic characters from B up to some number N (`` `c$66+! ``). The function joins the left argument on either side of the right argument (`{x,y,x}`).

In action:

```
 ("A"{x,y,x}/`c$66+!)'!6
("A"
 "ABA"
 "ABACABA"
 "ABACABADABACABA"
 "ABACABADABACABAEABACABADABACABA"
 "ABACABADABACABAEABACABADABACABAFABACABADABACABAEABACABADABACABA")
```

Comment: I think the sequence should be lowercase, but that costs no bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, <s>20</s> 17 bytes

```
97oU+98 r@X+Yd +X
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=OTdvVSs5OCByQFgrWWQgK1g=&input=Mw==)

#### How it works

```
         // Implicit: U = input integer
65oU+66  // Generate a range from 65 to U+66.
r@       // Reduce each item Y and previous value X in this range with this function:
X+Yd     // return X, plus the character with char code Y,
+X       // plus X.

         // Implicit: output last expression
```

### Non-competing version, 14 bytes

```
97ôU r@X+Yd +X
```

The `ô` function is like `o`, but creates the range `[X..X+Y]` instead of `[X..Y)`. [Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=OTf0VSByQFgrWWQgK1g=&input=Mw==)

I much prefer changing the 97 to 94, in which case the output for `5` looks like so:

```
^_^`^_^a^_^`^_^b^_^`^_^a^_^`^_^c^_^`^_^a^_^`^_^b^_^`^_^a^_^`^_^
```

Answer (score 1):

### Java, 219 bytes

My first code golf attempt. Probably can be golf'd further, but I'm hungry and going out to lunch.

```
public class a{public static void main(String[]a){String b=j("a",Integer.parseInt(a[0]),1);System.out.println(b);}public static String j(String c,int d,int e){if(d>=e){c+=(char)(97+e)+c;int f=e+1;c=j(c,d,f);}return c;}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
public class a {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        String string = addLetter("a", Integer.parseInt(a[0]), 1);
        System.out.println(string);
    }

    public static String addLetter(String string, int count, int counter) {
        if (count >= counter) {
            string += (char) (97 + counter) + string;
            int f = counter + 1;
            string = addLetter(string, count, f);
        }
        return string;
    }
}
```

Pretty straightforward brute force recursive algorithm, uses `char` manipulation.

Comment: You can omit the `public` keyword from `a` and `addLetter`/`j`.

Answer (score 1):

## Powershell, <s>53</s>,<s>46</s>,<s>44</s>,41 Bytes

```
1..$args[0]|%{}{$d+=[char]($_+96)+$d}{$d}
```

Pasting into console will generate erronous output on the second run since `$d` is not re-initialized.

Save 2 bytes by using +=
Save 3 bytes thanks to @TimmyD

Comment: @TimmyD Actually gets it down to 41 since I won't need the `(`,`)`.

Comment: No, that was my fault, I actually forgot to update it even though I said I did.

Comment: the script does not wirk with 0 and does not generate a uppercase letter

Answer (score 1):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 14 bytes

```
₵aØ@⟪¤ṇ3ṁ¤+ṫ⟫ₓ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9nYWlh///igrVhw5hA4p@qwqThuYcz4bmBwqQr4bmr4p@r4oKT//8z)

```
₵a		| Push lowercase alphabet
  Ø		| push lowercase string
   @         ₓ	| push the input and do everything between ⟪⟫ that many times
    ⟪¤		| swap
      ṇ		| take the last (first) character
       3ṁ	| push the 3rd item on the stack
         ¤+	| swap and concatenate
           ṫ⟫	| and palindromize
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 8 bytes

```
;gCåÈ+iY
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=O2dD5cgraVk)

```
;gCåÈ+iY     :Implicit input of integer
 g           :Index into
; C          :  Lowercase alphabet
   å         :  Cumulatively reduce, with an initial value of an empty string
    +        :    Append a copy of the current value
     i       :    Prepended with
      Y      :    The current letter
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 54 bytes

```powershell
param($n)for(;$n+1){$d+=[char]($i+++97-32*!$n--)+$d}$d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY9dCsIwEITfc4pYVk1MC7YKolLw9xQiEpsUhRprWlGoPXtda1VwYZmZj9mHTc83bbODTpIKYhrSokqllScGhsdny6ZghM8LUCLcRAdptwyOQojxyBsEvRYYz@MCVAmqKgmZMeKyvku78y5H56OTC1n74OX3colb58E7R7irRms@/HHV6PovY49w@qBtWhCKA8aloO@pjnKt8APYvbHV2TXJEXTwMTA1dIA13Iv05XvFJ5@6Q8rqCQ)

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), 24 chars, 48 bytes

```
{⍵<0:⍬⋄k,⎕A[⍵+1],k←∇⍵-1}
```

test:

```
  f←{⍵<0:⍬⋄k,⎕A[⍵+1],k←∇⍵-1}
  f 0
A
  f 1
ABA
  f 2
ABACABA
  f 3
ABACABADABACABA
  f 4
ABACABADABACABAEABACABADABACABA
```

Comment: Doesn’t APL use it’s own code page with every character one byte, making this 24 bytes?

Comment: @Loovjo for what I know  Nars Apl has character set 2 bytes for character

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>20 19</s> 17 bytes

```apl
⎕a[¯1↓⊥¨⍨,⍳2,⎕⍴2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob2pm/qO2CQZcjzra00DcxOhD6w0ftU1@1LX00IpHvSt0HvVuNtIBSjzq3WIU@x@o7H8alwFXGpchEBsBsTEQmwAA)

yet another apl answer

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/) `-r`, 43 bytes

`register_argc_argv` must be enabled for this to work.

```php
for($a=$b=a;$argv[1]--;$a.=++$b.$a);echo$a;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P8/Lb9IQyXRViXJNtFaJbEovSzaMFZXF8jUs9XWVknSU0nUtE5NzshXSbT@////v/yCksz8vOL/ukUk6TQFAA)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 51 bytes

An anonymous function that prints the output directly.

```php
function($n){for($a=$b=a;$n--;$a.=++$b.$a);echo$a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExDoAgDAXQqzj8AUJgc6qNZynEBhdojE7Gs9f3rJtvu3VboOz6jHafcwSM@Oq8AoRRWQgjZ4IUTgm1QCIdrU8IfU7QsEbyHw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 41 bytes

```
1-011v $<
v::+&_:#^!_:1+v
>:0\:^,+"`"$%:<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/31DXwNCwTEHFhqvMykpbLd5KOU4x3spQu4zLzsogxipOR1spQUlF1crm/39jAA)

Probably some room for improvement here.

#### Explanation

The sequence is generated using its recursive definition. First, we initialize the stack with the 4 values `(1, input+2), (0, -1)`. Each pair `(a, b)` on the stack is an "instruction" used in generating the sequence, which, when executed, gets popped and does the following:

- if `a == 0`:

  - if `b == -1`, terminate
  - if `b == 0`, do nothing
  - if `b != -1 and b != 0`, print `b+96` as an ASCII character
- if `a != 0`, push `(b-1, b-1), (0, b-1), (b-1, b-1)`

The top two items on the stack are continuously run as a sequence-building instruction until the program terminates.

Worth noting that `&+` is used the first time around to get the input, as well as every subsequent time as a decrement (because when there is no more input, `&` returns -1)

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 69 bytes

```lua
f=function(n)return n<1 and"a"or f(n-1)..string.char(97+n)..f(n-1)end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TclbCoMwEEbhd1cRfJogBlNvFOpighoV5FemyfpjoBTm7eOcM7qU/OQj5nBcIGheQ2QofKxyWEpXXqw8obbamG/gA5uZd8f0Hivk9FsrlnTnF8hTo3XxtxV@CbfCnXAvPAiP2ekB)

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>58</s> 53 bytes

```cpp
string f(int n){return n--?f(n)+char(98+n)+f(n):"a";}
```

- 5 bytes saved by `ceilingcat`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcy7DoMwDAXQuXyFRZdEiKFPtU1EvyUygUYCg/KYEN@eBnUoQ6Zrn2sZ57nuEePREA6h1SDN5LzVamyKvyUx1DdFcCmA1KjdrFCD862IvxI6ZsgD8cVqHywB1fW7Y8Qr/CjLno8qjdv@KlUp1rgdj8oQ47AUB5yCBynTkxPfUlM7iD2f83zJ8zXPtzzfd7zGLw)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), 9 bytes

```
AćsI£vDyý
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f8Uh7seehxWUulYf3/v9vCgA)

Also runs with the new 05AB1E version.

code:

```
A       push the lowercase alphabet
ć       extract first character of that ["bcdefg....", "a"]
s       swap both strings ["a", "bcdefg...."]
I£      drop all letters of the alphabet after the index defined by input
v       for each character 
  D     duplicate last stack entry
  yý    join by current letter
        implicitly close for-loop and print top of stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## k4, 23 bytes

```
{.Q.a x{x,(1+|/x),x}/0}
```

---

```
      x{           }/0  / do {func} x times, passing output of last iteration as input (first input is 0)
          (1+|\x)       / 1 + max x
        x,       ,x     / join x either side
 .Q.a                   / index into alphabet
```

executed with inputs [0,4) we get:

```
  {.Q.a x{x,(1+|/x),x}/0}'[0 1 2 3]
("a";"aba";"abacaba";"abacabadabacaba")
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 11 bytes

```
Eɽƛǐ2O;97+C
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=s&code=E%C9%BD%C6%9B%C7%902O%3B97%2BC&inputs=4&header=&footer=)

```
Eɽ          # 0...2**n
  ƛ   ;     # Mapped to...
   ǐ2O      # Count of 2 in prime factorisation
       97+C # Add 97 and get charcodes
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 14 bytes

```lisp
a?z@aWRREa-1'a
```

Takes the integer as a command-line argument. [Try it here!](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/pip) Or, here's a 15-byte equivalent in Pip Classic: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/0b7KITE8SCMtUddQUz3x////JgA)

#### Explanation

A recursive full program.

```lisp
a?              ; Is the argument truthy (non-zero)?
                ; If so:
  z@a           ;  Get the letter of the lowercase alphabet at index a
     WR         ;  and wrap it in two copies of
       RE       ;  the result of a recursive call
         a-1    ;  with argument a-1
                ; Otherwise:
            'a  ;  Return the letter a
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 43 bytes

```python
a=lambda n:'a'[n:]or(b:=a(n-1))+chr(97+n)+b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcE7DoAgDADQ3VN0sw1xMA4oCScxDsUfJFpIw@Lp8b3y1Zhlmou2xv7hNxwM4nruV3FbVgzOM8owEpk9Ki7WCJnQrqyQIAkoy32iJddB0SQVGRNR@wE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 48 bytes

```arturo
f:$->x[(0=x)?->"a"->++++f x-1to :char x+97f x-1]
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?cZCVQK)

```
f:$->x[               ; a function named f taking an argument x
    (0=x)?            ; is x zero?
    ->"a"             ; then return "a"
    ->                ; otherwise,
        ++++          ; append three things together
        f x-1         ; f(x-1)
        to :char x+97 ; x converted to character
        f x-1         ; f(x-1)
]                     ; end function
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), 80 bytes

1-indexed

```
listen to N
X's 0
O's ""
while N-X
cast X+97 in C
let O be+C+O
let X be+1

say O
```

[Try it](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

Answer (score 0):

## Matlab, 54 bytes

Just a straight forward recursive implementation.

```
function s=f(n);s='';if n>-1;k=f(n-1);s=[k,n+97,k];end
```

I first thought I could do better by using anonymous functions, but it turned out to be way longer, but I thougt I still share it:

```
i=@(b,c)c{2-b}();
a=@(n,f)i(n<0,{@()'',@()[f(n-1,f)),n+97,f(n-1,f)]});
ba=@(n)a(n,a);
```

Answer (score 0):

## J, <s>30</s> 28 bytes ([Try it online!](http://tryj.tk/))

I just found out that `a(0) = "a"`, which chopped of 2 bytes.

```
u:97+(0:`($:@<:,],$:@<:)@.*)
```

Usage:

```
   u:97+(0:`($:@<:,],$:@<:)@.*) 2
abacaba
```

How it works:

```
u:97+(0:`($:@<:,],$:@<:)@.*) n NB. pseudocode:
                               NB. input as n
                               NB. function as generate_tree
u:                             NB.   convert_to_ASCII(
  97+                          NB.     add_to_all(97,
     (xx`yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy@.z)   NB.       if z then y or x:
                          *    NB.         z: n>0?
      0:                       NB.         x: 0
         ($:@<:,],$:@<:)       NB.         y:
          ppppp,q,rrrrr        NB.           concat(p,q,r):
          $:@<:                NB.             p:
          $:@                  NB.               generate_tree(
             <:                NB.                 n-1)
                ]              NB.             q: n
                  $:@<:        NB.             r: generate_tree(n-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke, 11 bytes (noncompeting)

```
G@QVk?tQG@:
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=G%40QVk%3FtQG%40%3A&input=3)

```
G@          - s = alphabet[input]
  QV        - repeat input times:
     ?tQ    -   input -= 1
        G@  -  alphabet[^]
    k     : - s = s.replace("", ^)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
ø⁸╵ｚｍ｛＋│
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JUY4JXUyMDc4JXUyNTc1JXVGRjVBJXVGRjREJXVGRjVCJXVGRjBCJXUyNTAy,i=Mw__,v=8)

[7 bytes](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JUY4JXUyMDc4JXVGRjVBJXVGRjREJXVGRjVCJXVGRjBCJXUyNTAy,i=Mw__,v=8) taking the index starting with 1, or hacky [6 bytes](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXUyNTc1JXVGRjVBJXVGRjREJXVGRjVCJXVGRjBCJXUyNTAy,i=MyUwQQ__,v=8) by taking input "with a trailing newline" (which together can sum up to [5 bytes](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjVBJXVGRjREJXVGRjVCJXVGRjBCJXUyNTAy,i=NCUwQQ__,v=8))

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 35 bytes

```perl6
{('a',{$_~chr(++$+97)~$_}...*)[$_]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv1pDPVFdp1olvi45o0hDW1tF29Jcs04lvlZPT09LM1olPrb2f3FipUKaRpyhgab1fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
‘R;ṭ¥/ịØa
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARwA4/9qZWxsef//4oCYUjvhua3CpS/hu4vDmGH///80)

It would be 8 were it not for the requirement for the sequence to start with zero = a.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 169 bytes

```js
x=function(n){var r="";for(var i=1;i<=Math.pow(2,n)-1;i++){for(var j=i;j>=0;j--){if(!(i%Math.pow(2,j))){r+="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".slice(0,n)[j];break;}}}return r;}
```

#### [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYxdT8IwGEb/ylxi0jejC3hFUmqiqIgIKH4C8aLUTlqXdnlXYEmz3z7HBYmXz8k5jxF7UUrUhafWfaumqXi2s9JrZ4mFsBcYIY9jljkkx6F5j@kBnwq/TQt3IBcdC7RFSQLh5BiumbnkXWYohaAzckb0@b/CAEDAhMdX18Ob27vR/fhh8jidzZ@eFy@vb@8fn8tVnJa5lop02/u1@WIbVOKX1XWNyu/QRsjqRjpbulylufshFekDNH8)

#### Live demo:

```js
x=function(n){var r="";for(var i=1;i<=Math.pow(2,n)-1;i++){for(var j=i;j>=0;j--){if(!(i%Math.pow(2,j))){r+="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".slice(0,n)[j];break;}}}return r;}

console.log(x(prompt("Input depth of ABACABA Pattern")))
```

#### Explanation:

> ```js
> x = function(n){ // created function, and yes, I omitted var
>   var r = ""; // declaring variable to be returned
>   for (var i = 1; i <= Math.pow(2, n) - 1; i++){ // this loop creates each letter in the pattern; "Math.pow(2, n) - 1" is the length of the pattern at depth n
>     for (var j = i; j >= 0; j--){ // this loop finds the greatest power of 2 that i is divisible by, since that can be used to find the correct character for that index
>       if (! (i % Math.pow(2, j) ) ){ // the modulo part checks the divisibility of 2^j; the "!" replaces "=== 0" 
>         r += "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".slice(0,n)[j]; // appending character to r
>         break; // exits loop once greatest power of 2 i is divisible by is found
>       }
>     }
>   }
>   return r;
> }
> ```

Comment: The `x=` can be omitted if you do not refer to it anywhere else, and also I think `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".slice(0,n)[j]` can be `(j+10).toString(36)` because (1) `.slice(0,n)` is not necessary here, and (2) `(j+10).toString(36)` returns `j+10` in base 36, which should be equivalent to your code.

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 63 bytes

```
#(loop[r""i 0](if(= i %)r(recur(str r(char(+ i 97))r)(inc i))))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Mumps (InterSystems), 46 bytes

```
S Q="",A=65 R N F I=0:1:N{S Q=Q_$C(A+I)_Q} W Q
```

InterSystems' version of Mumps (some say M, InterSystems likes to call it "Cache Object Script") allows delineating loops with braces which helps keep things on a single line; GT.M would be a few characters longer.

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ö▬⌐ç╗à╢
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=9416a987bb85b6&i=1%0A2%0A3%0A15&a=1&m=2)

This uses 1-based indexing.

[0-based indexing costs another byte](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=877468e95e969ec8&i=0%0A1%0A2%0A14&a=1&m=2)